# independent jobs print into the same file (OpenMP)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have written a code that simply gets a parameter `D` and print two numbers, `(x,y)`, in a text file. I am going to use multiple cores to run the independent serial code in parallel.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int D=10; D<26; D++)
    system(("./serial "+ to_string(D)).c_str());
```

What is the best way to print the results correctly?
I can later sort the file by the first column. So I only want to be sure that the code correctly puts each y beside its x.
Do you have any idea?
Is it a good method to simply use multiple cores to parallel a serial code?

Comment: i dont know the best way, but imho having multiple threads writing into the same file isnt a good idea. Why dont you collect the data first and then write it to file? Writing to the file is sequential anyhow

Comment: It was the first thing I considered. There would be thousands of files each having only two number. so I was wondering if there is a clean way of collecting the data?

Comment: make an array with thousands of entries, once it is filled write it to a file

Comment: but the jobs are independently running and don't see a common array. Maybe I write a bash script to read the files(named by independent parameter `D`) and copy the content into the `results.txt` and delete the other files

Comment: *but the jobs are independently running and don't see a common array.*  That seems to contradict one of the basics of an OpenMP program - shared memory programming means that all threads can see common arrays.

Comment: OpenMP does not support _parallel I/O_ (in contrast to, e.g., MPI). If you need to access a single file from multiple threads, you basically need to do this inside `critical` sections.